# Can provider send phone number along with device token to APNs server for push notification ?

Tags: ios, security, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

iOS Device Token for the push notification is an opaque identifier of a device.
The provider can't get any device related information from the device token.

Based on Apple Push Notification programming guide, the provider needs to provide device token and payload to APNs server for the push notification.

Can provider send phone number OR bundle id OR  advertising identifier OR vendor identifier to the APNs Server when the provider send token and payload to APNs server during push notification ?
So, the APNs server will not send the message to device if the device token is not associated with any device properties (like phone number or advertising identifier or vendor id).

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question:

> Based on Apple Push Notification programming guide, the provider needs to provide device token and payload to APNs server for the push notification.

If you could provide the phone number, for example, you could simply use harvested phone numbers and spam people with push notifications. The token is not only for identifying the phone; you only get one if the user explicitly said "Yes, I want push notifications."

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I meant that not only phone number but phone number and device token can be sent to APNS by the provider.
In the apple programming guide, I have not found it but looking any other solution or work around.

Answer (score 0):

The only properties that determine if a push notification is delivered to an iOS application on a given device are the push certificate used to establish the connection with APNS (which determines the destination application) and the device token (which determines the destination device). Any other parameters you choose to include in your payload will have no effect on the delivery of the message.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that we implemented (and it works very well), is:

1. have the device token sent to the server upon registration
2. server stores that in a 'user_device' table (which ties the user to the device - once you get the info....  at this time you only have the token, so the userId is 0)
3. the user continues with their login info.....
4. as the user completes their login (going to the server for verification), include the token and match that up in the database (note that you could also just send it at this point, but we like to send the token in #2 so we could see how many people register devices but not log in...)

Now, you have a match-up from the user data to their deviceId and can then match up various USER properties (or even the device properties if you have gotten them from other means - like when the user signed in and completed their profile) and send the appropriate push notice.